# Adalm Pluto SDR - Second RX channel signal issues

Tags: antenna, signal, wireless, sdr, gnuradio

I have a Pluto SDR rev c, on which I just enable the second TX and RX channel. I am sending a simple sinusoidal signal at a specific frequency (fc), but different phase and amplitude, using the two TX channels. I am receiving the signal on the RX channel 1, and hence I am viewing it using the "QT GUI Frequency Sink".

[image: RX1 - Signal]

However, when I try to use the second channel - RX2, instead of RX1, I get different results.

[image: rx2 - Signal]

The gain of the signal has reduced on RX2 (-76.4 dBm), while I was expecting to see the same gain as RX1 (-59.14 dBm). I tried to change the phase of the TX Signal, but there is not much difference.

So my question is why am I seeing different results?

Comment: How are you reducing the gain in the second plot?  With such a low level signal a simple change in resistance may contribute to a change in the noise level.

Comment: I am using an Adalm Pluto SDR, and the first plot shows the received signal's gain, when the receiver is connected to RX1.
I am then testing the second RX channel of the SDR, by receiving the signal on RX2, rather than RX1.  
Both plots should show the same output (same gain), but the RX2 gain is different. This could be due to a phase difference between RX1 and RX2, but when I manually change the phase of the signal using a phase shift block in GNU Radio, I can't equate it to RX1.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were manually adjusting the gain/attenuation.  If you are absolutely sure that all settings are equal maybe look into a calibration for one channel or the other.